# MVC page with IEnumerable<TModel> expression helper

Tags: c#, generics, expression-trees, expression

I have a MVC partial view that its Model is an IEnumerable<SomeModel>.

The Html type is therefore HtmlHelper<IEnumerable<SomeModel>>
We have a custom WebViewPage that exposes in instance of ViewModel

```
public class SomeModel
{
    [Display("Model Id")]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [Display("The Name")]
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

public abstract class ViewModelWebViewPage : WebViewPage { }
public abstract class ViewModelWebViewPage<TModel> : ViewModelWebViewPage
{
    ... 
    public ViewModel<TModel> { get; set; }
}
```

The basic premise behind this is to drive client side template/binding expressions for Javascript templating systems, like Knockout or JQuery Templating, off the C# ViewModel definition

I'm writing a couple of methods to assist in getting the DisplayName for table headers ( basically the value of the Display attribute - our real version involves localization using a subclassed DataAnnotationsMetadataProvider and the IMetadataAware attribute )

```
public class ViewModel<TModel>
{
    public MvcHtmlString DisplayNameFor<TProperty>( Expression<Func<TModel, TProperty>> expression )
    {
        ModelMetadata metadata = ModelMetadata.FromLambdaExpression( expression, this.html.ViewData );
        return new MvcHtmlString(metadata.DisplayName);
    }

    public MvcHtmlString DisplayNameFor<TItem, TProperty>( Expression<Func<TModel, IEnumerable<TItem>>> expression, Expression<Func<TItem, TProperty>> itemExpression )
    {
        ModelMetadata metadata = ModelMetadata.FromLambdaExpression( itemExpression, new ViewDataDictionary<TItem>() );
        return new MvcHtmlString(metadata.DisplayName);
    }
}
```

In the view I would use this helper like...

```
@model IEnumerable<SomeModel>
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <!-- 
          "this" is a ViewModelViewWebPage<IEnumerable<SomeModel>>
          ViewModel is a ViewModel<IEnumerable<SomeModel>>
          m is an IEnumerable<SomeModel>, 
          item is of type SomeModel 
      -->
      <th>@ViewModel.DisplayNameFor( m => m, item => item.Id )</th>
      <th>@ViewModel.DisplayNameFor( m => m, item => item.Name )</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  ... remainder of table html
</table>
```

This all works, and I get the expected result in the rendered HTML

```
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Model Id</th>
      <th>The Name</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  ... remainder of table html
</table>
```

I don't like that I have to pass the current model in the first expression to boot strap the second as I would like to define a method in ViewModel<TModel> class that is able to understand that ViewModel<TModel> is actually a 
ViewModel<IEnumerable<TItem>>

```
<th>@ViewModel.DisplayNameFor( m => m.Id )</th>
```

I have managed to create a extension method

```
    public static MvcHtmlString DisplayNameFor<TItem, TValue>(this ViewModel<IEnumerable<TItem>> viewModel, Expression<Func<TItem, TValue>> expression)
    {
        ModelMetadata metadata = ModelMetadata.FromLambdaExpression(expression, new ViewDataDictionary<TItem>());

        return new MvcHtmlString(metadata.DisplayName);
    }
```

but I would like it part of the ViewModel class itself but I can seem to find a way of defining a DisplayNameFor method to infer the IEnumerable relationship.

I tried

```
    public MvcHtmlString DisplayNameFor<TItem, TValue>(Expression<Func<TItem, TValue>> expression)
        where TModel : IEnumerable<TItem>
    {
        ModelMetadata metadata = ModelMetadata.FromLambdaExpression(expression, new ViewDataDictionary<TItem>());

        return new MvcHtmlString(metadata.DisplayName);
    }
```

but that doesn't compile, as the TModel from the constraint doesn't belong the enclosing type, but it is expected as a Type parameter to the method.

Is it possible to define such a method signature inside the ViewModel<TModel> class that can enforce the TModel is a IEnumerable<TItem> relationship and therefore allow the expression argument to be a Func<TItem, TValue>, or am I going to have to live with an extension method.

Comment: I don't quite understand. That won't compile because the constraint won't work on a type parameter you haven't defined..

Comment: That's what I said at the end of the post...  My original thought was that the TModel type IS defined by the enclosed type that method was in... but it looks like the constraint system doesn't work that way

Comment: clarified the problem statement at the end... hope it makes it clearer

Comment: This feature is available in MVC4. Check System.Web.Mvc.Html.DisplayNameExtensions on source

Comment: Could someone clarify what user270 is talking about, It is not obvious